# Problem adding Android platform to NetBeans 6.9

Tags: android, netbeans

I've been using Netbeans 6.9 quite happily with Android for a few months but I completely wiped my SDK yesterday and now, after reinstalling it, I can't get Netbeans to create the Android platform. I can select the platform okay but once I press FINISH nothing ever appears in Netbeans. I've even re-installed Netbeans but no joy.

Could someone post the contents of their platform XML file for Android? I'm thinking I can just enter this file manually and have Netbeans pick it up.

Any other ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello, i am invoice of netbeans of platform xml file ..if you tell me where to find it i'll post it...

Comment: Thanks. It's in .netbeans/<version>/config/Services/Platforms/org-netbeans-api-java-Platform. I hope that's all I need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with netbeans 6.9.1, mine was related with some incompatibility between 32bit and 64bit java.

I have Win7 x64 and also had java x64. removed x64 java and installed x86 java without reinstalling netbeans probaly caused the problem
This solved it for me.

- uninstall netbeans
- uninstall all java jre and jdk's
- reinstall 32bit java
- reinstall netbeans
- reinstall nbandroid

Comment: Thanks, Webjin, that's got me going. And something I would never thought of looking at. I had 64-bit java version 21 but a 32-bit java version 22. I removed NetBeans, removed 1.6.0_22, and reinstalled Netbeans. I can now add my Android platform again. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can only recomend you use Eclips for developing for android.
2 major adventages are:
1. Easly install JDK wich is spesific for eclips.
2. You get an emulator built in, making debuging even fun ;)

Comment: The emulator is not built in - it's part of the Android SDK... it works exactly the same with Netbeans (assuming you have the 3rd party Android plugin by kenoi). And why should they stop using the IDE they like? This is NOT an answer to his question!

Answer (score 0):

on one forum i found:
simply cut and paste the yourandroidlocation/platforms/android-1.1 (what you prefer, your current android platform) folder to the yourandroidlocation/. no files will be overwritten and now the android.jar and the other folders are on the right position.

it solve for me....hi

Answer (score 0):

Note that this whole thread is obsolete now. The current version of android plugin for NetBeans ( http://www.nbandroid.org ) does not register Android platform in Java platform manager. Instead it looks into `.properties` files in your project to find Android SDK location and target platform that is used to build your project.

-Radim